# Código PHP dentro de un formulario de WPForms

Tags: php, wordpress, formularios, wordpress-plugin

Soy nuevo en PHP y tengo un duda...

Tengo un formulario de *WPforms* en *wordpress*, pero tiene algunas configuraciones de seguridad; en cualquier caso, he ingresado este código de *PHP* para obtener la fecha dentro de un campo de texto para un contrato:

Éste es el texto del campo:

```
CONTRATO DE MANTENIMIENTO PREVENTIVO
ANTECEDENTES:
Al `<?php echo date("j");  ?>` del mes de `<?php echo date("F"); ?>` del año `<?php echo date("Y"); ?>`, el equipo....
```

Mi duda es si estoy haciendo algo mal o si el sistema de *wpforms* está impidiendo que el código *PHP* funcione normalmente.

El resultado que obtengo es el siguiente:

[image: captura de pantalla del formulario]

Gracias por ayudar.

Comment: Creo que no es posible incrustar codigo PHP en el template de WPForms (no encuentro referencias para ello), hay otras maneras propuestas de incluir codigo personalizado https://wpforms.com/developers/how-to-add-custom-php-or-javascript-for-wpforms/

Answer (score 1):

La manera recomendada de hacerlo es usando [***smart tags***](https://wpforms.com/docs/how-to-use-smart-tags-in-wpforms/).

Existen [instrucciones de como implementar smart tags personalizados](https://wpforms.com/developers/how-to-create-a-custom-smart-tag/) donde puedes incluir ciertos elementos dinamicos para incluir. Siguiendo el ejemplo, puede ser algo como este codigo ([se agrega en el archivo `functions.php`](https://wpforms.com/developers/how-to-add-custom-php-or-javascript-for-wpforms/) del tema actual:

```
/**
 * Register the Smart Tag so it will be available to select in the form builder.
 *
 * @link   https://wpforms.com/developers/how-to-create-a-custom-smart-tag/
 *
 */
function wpf_dev_register_smarttag( $tags ) {
 
    // Key is the tag, item is the tag name.
    $tags['dia_actual'] = 'Dia actual';
    $tags['mes_actual'] = 'Mes actual';
 
    return $tags;
}
add_filter( 'wpforms_smart_tags', 'wpf_dev_register_smarttag' );
 
/**
 * Process the Smart Tag.
 *
 * @link   https://wpforms.com/developers/how-to-create-a-custom-smart-tag/
 *
 */
function wpf_dev_process_smarttag( $content, $tag ) {
 
        // Reemplazar el tag con codigo generado en PHP
    if ( 'dia_actual' === $tag ) {
        $content = str_replace( '{dia_actual}', date("j"), $content );
    }
    if ( 'mes_actual' === $tag ) {
        $content = str_replace( '{mes_actual}', date("F"), $content );
    }
 
    return $content;
}
add_filter( 'wpforms_smart_tag_process', 'wpf_dev_process_smarttag', 10, 2 );
```

Luego solo se necesita el smart tag adecuado para incluirlo en el form (ej: {dia_actual})

```
Al {dia_actual} del mes de ...
```